# Redirect to login page with two sessions

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have user session that after it ends the website will direct you to the user login page and I did this using `global.asax` file, now I have another session for admin login.

My problem is when user session ends it will only direct you to user login page

so I tried adding if session end for admin using the below code:

```
    void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Code that runs when a new session is started  
        if (Session["user_name"] != null)
        {
            //Redirect to Welcome Page if Session is not null  
            Response.Redirect("user_login.aspx");

        }
        else if (Session["user_name"] == null)
        {
            //Redirect to Login Page if Session is null & Expires   
            Response.Redirect("login_page.aspx");

        }
        // Code that runs when a new session is started  
        if (Session["admin_name"] != null)
        {
            //Redirect to Welcome Page if Session is not null  
            Response.Redirect("admin_page.aspx");

        }
        else if (Session["admin_name"] == null)

        {
            //Redirect to Login Page if Session is null & Expires   
            Response.Redirect("admin_login=.aspx");

        }

    }
```

but I got this error message:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.Web.HttpException' occurred
>   in System.Web.dll

and here is the details:

```
The System.Web.HttpException is not handled by the user code
HRESULT = -2147467259
Message = Cannot forward after sending HTTP headers.
Source = System.Web
Error code = -2147467259
WebEventCode = 0
Stack Tracking:
At System.Web.HttpResponse.Redirect (URL string, logical address, permanent logical address)
At System.Web.HttpResponse.Redirect (URL string)
At WebApplication3.Global.Session_Start (Dispatch object, EventArgs e)     in c: \ Users \ abdullatif \ Documents \ Visual Studio 2012 \ Projects \     WebApplication3 \ WebApplication3 \ Global.asax.cs: line 48
At System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule.RaiseOnStart (EventArgs e)
At System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule.CompleteAcquireState ()
At System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule.BeginAcquireState (Object     Source, EventArgs e, AsyncCallback cb, extraData Object)
At         System.Web.HttpApplication.AsyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplicati    on.IExecutionStep.Execute ()
InnerException:
```

Comment: Look into the inner exception.

Comment: Yes, you should have more details in the `StackTrace` of the exception, if you can put it in your question it will help

Comment: @Jonathan Larouche I added more details for  the error

Comment: Follow duplicate/related issue link, it is really because of making Redirect upon new session that cause the error.

Comment: try Session.Abandon();